# asp.net hide download

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am making an application to edit mp3 files. After the editing is finished I want to present a link to download the file. I am just concerned that the file location, if known, can be abused for illegal files. What do I need to do so that, instead of presenting a link to a file on the server, I can store it in memory (which I already have using taglib) and then stream the download without storing it on the server.

Comment: How does storing the file in memory prevent the linked content from being "abused for illegal files"?

Comment: @JonathanWood I think the idea is that content generated by UserA shouldn't be downloaded by UserB.

Comment: I changed the question from being a yes/no to a 'how'.  The answer to the first question is "yes", which I assume isn't a sufficient answer for you.

Comment: @jonathan, what I meant was that..the file is stored in memory and what I will do (or want to do) further in the code is stream the file for download rather than save the file..therefore, there is no link for the file and hence no sharing possible!

Comment: Any alternate suggestions are also welcome

Comment: @pessi Well, you could just add security so that user's can only download files they've generated, but if you don't actually need to store the files why take up all that space on your server by saving it?  Streaming the file without saving it is the proper course of action.

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% understand the problem. Where "in memory" is this file held? Is it part of the session? If so, then only the current user on that session should be able to access the file (although storing things like that in the session would be dangerous, as IIS has a nasty habit of dropping sessions just when you don't want it to)

Comment: You can put the MP3 as a MemoryStream into Session (though I would recommend a VERY robust server architecture if you want a multi-user server storing dozens or hundreds of MP3s for users in Session). You can also control access behind a service layer; when given an MP3 to edit, you give the requesting client a cookie or other identifying token, then when you're done the client must give you the same token to get the file back, and you don't actually expose the MP3 as a hyperlinked location.

Comment: I am agree with @KeithS ..if you have a file stream then you can send a file via responce `page.Response.WriteFile(yourData, 0, yourData.Length);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an HTTP Handler to write the file to the user while masking the true location of the file on the server. This will enable you to enforce whatever rules you may have regarding the downloading of the file, such as a one time download.

See: [How to create an HTTP Handler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001)

The code inside the handler will need to be unique to your needs, but something along the following lines should help:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
   context.Response.ContentType = "Application/mp3"; 
   context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=mysong.mp3"); 
   context.Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Files/song.mp3")); 
}
```

You could use a [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) in case you don't want to save an actual file anywhere, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for the code. One question though, it is interesting you mention one time download..that is indeed what I want..can you suggest on how to achieve that?

Comment: You would need to add some logic to determine if the user is allowed to download the file. You could, for instance, add a record to the DB denoting that the user downloaded the file and check for that record before transmitting the file.